# Swift UITableViewRowAction different number of buttons on different rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

With the UITableViewRowAction can you have different number of buttons on each row? For instance I want one row with 3 actions and the rest with 2. Is it possible?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

if indexPath.row == 0 {
  let note = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: " Note ") { action, index in

    self.notePopUpCalled()
  }
  note.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.informationColour

  let infomation = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: " Info ") { action, index in

    self.informationPopUpCalled()
  }
  infomation.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.appColour

let Diagram = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: " Diagram ") { action, index in

    self.diagramPopUpCalled()
  }
  note.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.informationColour
  return [note, information, diagram]


} else {
  let note = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: " Note ") { action, index in

  }
  note.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.informationColour

  let infomation = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: " Info ") { action, index in

  }
  infomation.backgroundColor = GlobalColourConstants.appColour
  return [note, information, nil]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes this is possible**. The method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

returns an array of actions for each index path. Therefore you can return different set of actions for each row.

Comment: I have used that but where I cannot let it accept less than a full array. I tried passing nil but it didn't work.

Comment: What about passing an empty array? However, returning nil should also be possible since the method declaration allows nil as a return value.

Comment: That is correct I can pass return [note, information, ] and then in the one with three  [note, information, diagram]